# Another way of grouping shapes in kineticJS - rather than using Group?

Tags: kineticjs

I have two groups (group1, group2) which both contain rectangles. Each of these groups is draggable. When I move a shape (group or rectangle in my case) and it overlaps with the other I trigger an event and add these two groups to another group (a super group) one which will be also draggable. The way I am doing this right now is by creating a supergroup which contains both groups as follows:

```
group1.add(cube1);
group2.add(cube2);
superGroup.add(group1);
superGroup.add(group2);
```

Even though this seems to work for the simple case of adding, for more complex cases this becomes cumbersome and inefficient.

So my question is:

Is there any other way of grouping shapes rather than by adding it to a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a third superGroup, how about merging group1 into group2 (or visa-versa).

This could be accomplished by adjusting the x/y of all group1 children and then moving them to group2.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/BkfkC/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var g1=new Kinetic.Group({x:10,y:10,draggable:true});layer.add(g1);
var g2=new Kinetic.Group({x:60,y:60,draggable:true});layer.add(g2);

var circle1a = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:20,
    y:20,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
});
g1.add(circle1a);

var circle1b = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:120,
    y:120,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
});
g1.add(circle1b);

var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:20,
    y:20,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
});
g2.add(circle2);

layer.draw();


function mergeG1intoG2(g1,g2){
    var g2pos=g2.position();
    var g1Children=g1.getChildren();
    n=g1Children.length-1;
    while(n>=0){
        var child=g1Children[n--];
        var pos=child.getAbsolutePosition();
        child.x(pos.x-g2pos.x);
        child.y(pos.y-g2pos.y);
        child.moveTo(g2);
    };
    g1.destroy();
    layer.draw();
}

    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        mergeG1intoG2(g1,g2);    
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myButton">Merge red+green group into blue group</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as your code is very useful. What I didn't mention to the question is that I still want to preserve the information about the subgroups when the new group is created. I was thinking to add an attribute to each rectangle which declares in which group it belongs. So even if I move it to a new group, that attribute will still remain the subgroup information.

Comment: No problem--you can use node names to retain each node's previous group information.  Assign all group1 nodes the name:"g1".  Then you can use layer.find(".g1") to fetch a collection of all the nodes that used to be in g1.